# org agenda: how to show only todo's with deadline?

Tags: org-agenda, org-mode

Is it possible to make the agenda views to only show tasks with a deadline, hence skipping all tasks containing only scheduled time?

The reason for this question is that I am NOT using scheduled time for when to start on a task, like having an appointment with my self, but instedad I am using scheduled time only for determining when a task will be visible in my task list. Hence I typically work on tasks that have their scheduled time days or weeks back in time. Of this reason, it is only the deadline-tasks I want to see in my agenda views. Is that possible?

Thanks for any suggestions, hints or help.

Comment: Consider using `org-agenda-list` with `(org-agenda-entry-types '(:deadline))`  My notes indicate that I previously used this to exclude scheduled -- i.e., specifying just deadline serves to exclude scheduled.  Here is an excerpt from my `org-agenda-custom-commands`:  `(agenda "Events" ((org-agenda-span 'month) (org-agenda-show-all-dates nil) (org-agenda-entry-types '(:deadline)) (org-deadline-warning-days 0) ))`

Comment: @lawlist Can you convert your comment to an answer so it can be upvoted and accepted?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is more than one way to accomplish the task outlined in the quesition of this thread.  My preferred method is to use `org-agenda-list` with the `org-agenda-entry-types` set to `:deadline` only, which serves to exclude `:scheduled`.  Note that `org-agenda-entry-types` is a list that can be more than one element -- for additional information on that variable, type `M-x describe-variable RET org-agenda-entry-types RET`.  The following is a sample entry in the `org-agenda-custom-commands` that will cause `org-agenda-list` to activate using (in part) the specified criteria -- I prefaced *in part* because certain variables can be globally set elsewhere (either by default or by custom setup) that will affect the behavior of `org-agenda-list`:

```lisp
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands '(
  ("1" "Events" agenda "display deadlines and exclude scheduled" (
    (org-agenda-span 'month)
    (org-agenda-time-grid nil)
    (org-agenda-show-all-dates nil)
    (org-agenda-entry-types '(:deadline)) ;; this entry excludes :scheduled
    (org-deadline-warning-days 0) ))
    ))
```